# Ajax response is undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm a newbie coder. I'm trying to insert the var cPrice in my front-end HTML page. However, it is undefined and I can't figure out why.

```
///////////// Display Pop-up finciton //////////////////
//Start//

$('#button1').on('click', function() {
// Show the popup
$('#openPopup').show();
// Get the symbol and name and show it in the popup
const symbolID = document.getElementById("symbolSearch").value.toUpperCase();
document.getElementById("currentSymbol").innerHTML = symbolID;



$.get("http://localhost:5000/placeOrder", function(err, price) {
    console.log(price.currentPrice);

    var cPrice = price.currentPrice // On the server-side it prints the correct value.

    console.log(cPrice) // However, here the front-end value is undefined.
    if (err) { console.log(err) } else {
        document.getElementById("currPrice").innerHTML = cPrice
    }

});



// Execute the function for retrieving the price
//userAction();
```

Comment: could you get the result with curl or postman ?

Comment: Yes, the result is 148.6

Comment: your code doese show any err ?

Comment: No. I've removed the .currentPrice  and now instead of undefined, it shows "success".

Comment: your result is in err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs: [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for the `success` function callback:
the **first argument** is the PlainObject **data**

> `jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`
> ***fn* success**
> Type: Function( **data**, textStatus, jqXHR )
> A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds. Required if dataType is provided, but you can use null or jQuery.noop as a placeholder.

There's also a

> **Deprecation notice**:
> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback methods are **removed as of jQuery 3.0**. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

therefore you'd better go with a more readable code using `.done()` and `.fail()`:

```js
$.get("http://localhost:5000/placeOrder")
  .done((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.currentPrice);
  })
  .fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
    console.log(jqXHR);
  });
```